# Upload failed for newer version apk on google play

Tags: android, google-play

I updated an application with different version and code. Then signed the apk by 'Right click->Android Tools->Export signed application package' using the same keystore of previous version apk.
But while uploading it to google play, getting following error. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with me?

"Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

SHA1: D6:E1:7F:65:4D:BF:B5:B0:F8:FB:D3:8F:F7:5A:40:B6:62:EA:98:EB

and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):

SHA1: 96:85:B8:57:87:29:4F:8B:AC:C3:26:29:D0:F5:A6:63:30:D6:0C:A3"

Comment: sounds just like it says, your using the wrong certificate, check your keystore, make sure

Comment: There is zero doubt here.  You've used the wrong certificate.

Answer (score 5):

I had the problem of "Upload Error".  It turned out to be a browser ( Chrome ) cache problem, and clearing the browser cache in Chrome, solved the problem.  I was able to upload the same apk and publish without any problem after clearing the browser cache.

Comment: +1 because this solved my problem (which is the title of this question), although I did not have the signature problem, this answer still can help others

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem also. In my case The problem occurred when i update my project.

1. I imported project from Android Studio 0.4.3 to Android Studio 0.8.9,
2. I signed apk with The same key,
3. When i upload apk to Google play i have error "Upload failed You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. (...)".

So.

1. I downgrade my project to 0.4.3,
2. Signed with The same key,
3. Upload without any problems.

I don't know how it even possible but it will work. I have hopes it will be helpful for you.